# Placing mp4 files in public or src folder -> create-react-app Best practices

Tags: video, create-react-app, directory-structure

I am just about to deploy react application and was wondering if I should place a background video in the src or public folder.

I currently have an assets folder in src from which I serve the mp4 background video. Works like a charm on localhost.

I have already googled this question to no avail. The create-react-app documentation doesn't give any advice nor mentions handling of larger video files at all.

Really appreciate if anyone could enlighten me in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As it is **suggested** in the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system):

> If you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by **webpack**. Instead, it will be copied into the build folder untouched.

It's better to put these kinds of files into the `public` folder in order not to be engaged with `FileLoader` of **Webpack** on the build process, however, you can also use the assets folder but `webpack` will consider them as **assets** and will add a `chunk hash` at the end and put the **reference** in the `bundle` which will be created.

Comment: As stated in above question I read the documentation. I have never setup webpack myself so the jargon you use to explain is unfortunately not very helpful.